# Is it possible to include the filetypes and their counts in the GSA Dynamic Navigation?

Tags: google-search-appliance

As the title says.

We know it's possible to search by filetype with the query prefix, like 'filetype:pdf' for example.

But we would like to include it in the dynamic navigation, to automatically have it filtered & counted.

Is this possible with filetypes? Or is it only possible with metadata.

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/68/admin_searchexp/images/dynamic_nav.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Navigation only works with metadata.  There is a separate Google code project:

http://code.google.com/p/parametric/

Which will allow you to setup a set of filters, but it does it's calculations in the browser.

*Updated*
With GSA 7.0, you can use entity extraction to create title type metadata and have that included in your dynamic nav (along with say...source/collection)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but as of GSA v7.0 you can use entity recognition to create a filetype entity and then include this in your dynamic navigation.

You could create instances similar to this:

```
 <instance>
   <name>PDF</name>
   <pattern>.*pdf$</pattern>
   <store_regex_or_name>name</store_regex_or_name>
 </instance>
```

It's not perfect because v7.0 this will match on PDF filenames within documents as well as in URLs but it's a good start.

In order to have this match only PDF filenames from v7.2 onwards, and not references to ".pdf" in a document or Web page, change the "Application Area" from "All" to "Url" when you are adding the entity.

Another option would be to create a collection for each of the file types that you are interested in and display these as filters above or below your dynamic navigation. Obviously you need to know in advance what file types you want to filter on but this approach gives you more control over what's included and what's not (although you will lose the ability to display doc counts for each file type).

[Entity Recognition Documentation](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/admin_console_help/crawl_entity_recognition.html)